# Category pages return recv() failed (104: connection reset..) Magento 1.9 multistore + nginx | php7.1 fpm

Tags: php, magento, nginx, connection-reset

I have a multi store magento1.9 environment on ubuntu 15.04, Nginx 1.9.15, php7.1 fpm. 5 store run on it. Surprisingly, from last 5 days, two of the stores throw below error. This happens to all category pages with products.

recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client:

We tried all other suggestions around timeouts, buffer sizes but no luck. 
3 stores work absolutely well. We are stuck and your help would be appreciated.

Comment: The log file is added into the shared document attached https://drive.google.com/drive/u/5/folders/1fT7-FZdk1V_HH5o9L_agnx4k_-1fo6Di

Comment: Finally we solved it. In additions to following all suggestions around timeouts, buffer sizes etc, we also had to make sure the values matched for 'Name','Root Category' and 'Default Store View' for each of our non-working stores. Any difference in these values caused segfaults on php-fpm internally and resulted in 502 errors on web pages. I am not sure if it was specific to my stack. Anyways I could bring my two stores live, after these changes.